# SSL certification stats

Tags: tls, certificate-authority

Why is

https://w3techs.com/technologies/history_overview/ssl_certificate

saying Let’s Encrypt has 0.1% when

https://letsencrypt.org/stats/

says 32 million Fully-Qualified Let's Encrypt Domains Active?

32 million = 0.1%

32 000 million SSL certs? = 100%

The question is which of the two stat website is lying?

There isn't 32 000 000 000 HTTPS certs imho.

UPDATE: Maybe: "The Let's Encrypt roots were cross-signed by IdenTrust, who are number 2 in that table. "

Comment: We can't tell you why some website says something.

Comment: After digging into the data, you are trying to compare apples and oranges and picking which data you want to compare, at that. We can't answer such a constrained question, skewed so particularly, without primary data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from another forum:

> TLDR: Look at the IdenTrust numbers if you want to know the real Let's
>   Encrypt numbers.
>
> Not many people use Let's Encrypt's own root for their validation
>   chain when they use Let's Encrypt certificates. The Let's Encrypt root
>   is not propagated widely enough across clients.
>
> We (Let's Encrypt) have a cross-signature from IdenTrust, that's what
>   most people use because it's widely trusted. IdenTrust issuance is
>   otherwise very small, so you can effectively consider the IdenTrust
>   numbers in charts like this to be a proxy for Let's Encrypt.
>
> -Josh from Let's Encrypt

Comment: Please cite your sources. What forum?

Comment: ycombinator! :)

Comment: please edit your answer and provide a link